# weak version of a Baez-Crans 2-vector space?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra

Baez and Crans defined a 2-vector space to be a category internal to the category of vector spaces (say over the reals).  I am interested in categories that are equivalent to  Baez-Crans vector spaces but are not necessarily isomorphic.  Do such categories have a name?
Do they have a nice description?  For example $+$ seem  to make such a category into a symmetric monoidal category.  What about multiplication by scalars?

Answer (score 3):

Let T be the algebraic theory of vector spaces (in the sense of Lawvere). Then a T-algebra in the category of small categories is a Baez-Crans 2-vector space. You seem to be asking about pseudo-T-algebras? See [arXiv:math/0408298](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408298).

I am not sure what you could call these. "pseudo vector space"? "pseudo 2-vector space"?.

A vector space has an underlying commutative monoid, so a pseudo T-algebra gives a pseudo commutative monoid, which is nearly the same as a symmetric monoidal category. However this commutative monoid is not just a monoid but a group. So you will get an Abelian 2-group (which is a symmetric monoidal category in which everything is invertible (objects and morphisms)).

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the suggestions.  What do you do with scalar the multiplication?  Do you categorify the ground field? and weaken the notion of a module?